# Business meeting jargon- a "walkthrough" of a document

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, business-language

I'm writing a document and I need to discuss sessions during which one party presents a document and walks the other party through the document, reading each sentence out loud, asking for any comments or questions, and ending with a final edited document.

Is there a standard business jargon term for this? Does "walkthrough" work?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: This sounds like basic (out loud) group proofreading to me.

Comment: HI- it's not proofreading. They aren't correcting spelling/punctuation errors- they're looking for problems with the content.

Comment: That is part of proofreading.

Comment: That may be, but still, I'm looking for specific jargon I heard once in this context.

Comment: I'm not convinced *proofreading* would ordinarily include verification of *content* to most people. Besides which it's usually a solo process, not interactive. What you're talking about here is a document ***review*** meeting (or perhaps an ***approval*** process).

Comment: *Review* seems better to me. I wouldn't use *walkthrough* because that doesn't suggest the idea of the document changing as a result of the meeting.

Comment: *Walkthrough* seems fine and familiar to me, including if the process leads and is meant to lead to revisions.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your suggestions.
I am definitely not looking for "review". I'm looking for a more "jargonny" term. The main goal of the session is indeed to explain a written document to another party, whereas the actual review is a side process.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a **[Review](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/review)**

> A formal assessment or examination of something with the possibility or intention of instituting change if necessary

It is not a *[Walkthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkthrough)*. For example, when used in Software Engineering, a *[Walkthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_walkthrough)* is a specific IEEE standard process, that

> differs from software technical reviews in its openness of structure and its objective of familiarization.

So I recommend *Review*.

Comment: To add to this, depending on the context of the meeting, you may call this a "peer review" - these are quite common with technical documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was informed by the client that the term they use is:
"guided walkthrough"

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.
Ilan

Comment: Instead of posting this as an answer, you could edit your original question and add an "update" section to it, describing this. (:

Comment: Hi- didn't know that option was available. Will do so next time, thanks.